# Pagelines Feature Slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pagelines, pagelines-platformpro

I am using the jQuery slider that comes with Pagelines Platform Pro, and my question is:

Is there a way to make the feature names in the navigation bar link to pages, and still function as the navigation bar for the slideshow?

Right now I have it so the `pageEvent` is `mouseover` so that when you hover on the featurenav bar on a corresponding feature name it goes to that slide. Now I just need it to also go to that page when you click on the name in the slideshow nav bar.

Here is a link to the test site: [sysorexhosting.com](http://www.sysorexhosting.com/)

Comment: u shud put some code to help urself :) coz no one here can be bothered to check a whole website source-code to find ur problem lol at least tell us where you think the problem is

Answer (score 1):

so whats the problem. you have got an `<a>` tag with `#` in href. just replace it with your url

```
<a href="#" class=""> International Development</a>
```

Change it to

```
<a href="?page_id=19" class=""> International Development</a>
```

Comment: that works to make links that go to the page but I also need it to still navigate the slides. so that when you hover over it goes to that slide and then when you click it goes to that page. thanks